# Is it possible I would get hacked by using DNS service?

Tags: networking, security, dns

I heard some people say, it’s possible that some hackers can access PCs while using public DNS service because they’ll be vulnerable to them. However, paid DNS service requires credentials, so it’s not possible for anyone to access. My question is, is it possible that some hackers can access PCs or interact with the data flow, or steal personal information?

By DNS service I mean when connecting to a server that tells specific sites that you’re from a different place to unblock them.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of DNS service. DNS is Domain Name Resolution, and one of the things it does is translate from a domain name (like superuser.com) to an IP address (say, 190.93.244.58). It sounds as if you are thinking of a VPN which lets you select an exit point in a specific geographic region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DNS service is Domain Name Resolution. A DNS server takes a web URL (e.g. `www.google.com`) and translates it to an IP address (in Google’s case, `216.58.216.206`).  A DNS would not change what a website sees as your location.

It is theoretically possible that an attacker could pose as a public DNS server via a Man-in-the-Middle attack and redirect legitimate browser requests to lookalike phishing sites or sites that attempt to load malicious scripting and what have you.

This would, however, require access to a private network’s configuration or require the victim to be using a public or poorly secured network.

If you’re on a public network like many businesses offer, it’s possible, if unlikely, that an attacker is using hardware to imitate the public hotspot to capture data traffic.

If this is legitimately concerning you, you can, however, take a few easy steps to protect yourself whilst connected to a public network.

1. Do not preform any sensitive browsing (online banking, ordering things on Amazon, etc) on public networks.
2. When inputting a URL, prefix with `https://` to attempt to force the page to load securely.  If the network is compromised or the site’s security certificates are invalid, you will be unable to load the page, however.
3. Google Chrome (unsure about Firefox, I doubt IE does this) has a blacklist of reported malware and phishing sites and automatically blocks you from browsing to said pages.

There are slightly more advanced steps possible, like using a VPN to secure your public internet connection, but I'm not very familiar with VPN setup.